# Prime number counter changing from using methods to using a nested loop in java

Tags: java

I wrote a code that asks the user for a number and prints out all the prime numbers, for example if the user types in '5' it would print 2,3,5,7,11. I used a method and was curious how to change the code into using a nested for loop. any ideas?

```
   public static void main(String[] args) {

   System.out.println("Enter the amount of prime numbers to be printed: ");
    int limit = new Scanner(System.in).nextInt();
    int count=1;
    System.out.println("Printing prime number from 1 to " + limit);
    for(int number = 2; count<=limit; number++){
        //print prime numbers only
        if(isPrime(number)){
            System.out.println(number);
            count++; 
        }
       }

   }

     public static boolean isPrime(int number){
      for(int i=2; i<number; i++){
        if(number%i == 0){
            return false; //number is divisible so its not prime
        }
    }
    return true; 
       }
   }
```

Comment: It is a nested loop because you are calling `isPrime` within the for loop. Do you want to move the `for` loop within the `isPrime` method in the `main` method?

Comment: yeah i just don't want any methods other than the main method

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your existing `for` loop with this:

```
    for (int number = 2; count <= limit; number++) {
        // print prime numbers only
        boolean isPrime = true;
        for (int i = 2; i < number; i++) {
            if (number % i == 0) {
                isPrime = false; // number is divisible so its not prime
                break;
            }
        }
        if (isPrime) {
            System.out.println(number);
            count++;
        }
    }
```

Here is what needs to be done in steps:

- Move your `for` loop from `isPrime` method to `main` method
- Keep a flag denoting whether the number is prime or not
- If you find that the number is not prime, then instead of returning set the flag to `false` and break from the innermost loop.

Comment: @Progamminnoob you can accept the answer by clicking the big check mark besides the answer if it helped you.